# Using YouTube API V3 to get video for channelId is failing

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to search for videos using a query string, for a given channel ID.

When I search with just the query string (Q), it returns 11 items.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&q=Albion-Park-11012015-Race-1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

However when I add in the Channel ID, it returns 0 items (no error that I can see):

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&q=Albion-Park-11012015-Race-1&channelId=UCa2qaN3dR_335aFKIFmBhlw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

The channelId I'm using matches what it comes back as from the first query, so I don't think it's just an incorrect channelID.

I'm experiencing this both via the .NET client library and on the YouTube doco page that includes a test bed - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Yeah ... this is a strange one.  I noted that if you change the '11012015' to a different string for videos in that channel, say '07012015' ... you do get videos coming back even with the channelID. Because YouTube search works on probabilistic relevance rather that actual database keyword searching, to me this is a sign that there's something not working quite right in their relevance algorithm. Perhaps they're in the middle of tweaking it? You may want to report it on the bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that since it seems it's not just me having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the following two queries, both returned 11 total results from the [Data API v3 search.list explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it):

Without channel ID:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&q=Albion-Park-11012015-Race-1&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

With channel ID:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&q=Albion-Park-11012015-Race-1&channelId=UCa2qaN3dR_335aFKIFmBhlw&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

I'm not sure what the problem was when you wrote this, but it seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for checking this now, I see the same, ithat the underlying issue appears to be resolved, so can improve my use of the API now.